# Vim- need timer for autosave

Tags: vim

In vim, I have autosave to file with:

```
augroup write_it
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertLeave * write
    autocmd TextChanged * write
augroup END
```

It works really good. But I need to place a wait in there for when I rapidly delete characters in command mode `TextChanged`. Any ideas how? It is a nightmare with livereload and gulp tasks watchers for front end development.

I tried `exec 'sleep 2'` but vim is async and it's useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the help for `CursorHold` and `CursorHoldI` events. They are triggered after some period of inactivity according to the `'updatetime'` option. You can use them.

There is also an `autowrite`. Anyway, it can go really complicated, so in my opinion your best alternative is to reuse code from who already thought about all this :-)

• The [AutoSave Plugin: https://github.com/907th/vim-auto-save.git](https://github.com/907th/vim-auto-save.git)